# Swift Dictionary Get Key for Values

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have a dictionary defined as:

```
let drinks = [String:[String]]()

drinks = ["Soft Drinks": ["Cocoa-Cola", "Mountain Dew", "Sprite"], 
"Juice" :["Orange", "Apple", "Grape"]]
```

How can I get the key, for a given value.

```
let key = (drinks as NSDictionary).allKeysForObject("Orange") as! String
print(key)
//Returns an empty Array. Should return "Juice"
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
func findKeyForValue(value: String, dictionary: [String: [String]]) ->String?
{
    for (key, array) in dictionary
    {
        if (array.contains(value))
        {
            return key
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Call the above function which will return an optional String?

```
let drinks = ["Soft Drinks": ["Cocoa-Cola", "Mountain Dew", "Sprite"],
        "Juice" :["Orange", "Apple", "Grape"]]

print(self.findKeyForValue("Orange", dictionary: drinks))
```

This function will return only the first key of the array which has the value passed.

Comment: Solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Returns only the first key even if there is more than one.

Comment: func findKeysForValue(value: String, dictionary: [String: [String]]) -> [String]
{
    var keys = [String]()
    for (key, array) in dictionary
    {
        if (array.contains(value))
        {
            keys.append(key)
        }
    }
    
    return keys
}

Comment: @aby,,,
Thanks for help..!

Comment: @abintom how can i print these values in CollectionView ,date as in Sections and array data in rows

Comment: ["2019-08-01": [
    ["changed_time": "10:00 AM", "changed_date": "2019-08-01", "changed_diaper_type_name": "Wet"],
    ["changed_time": "02:00 PM", "changed_date": "2019-08-01", "changed_diaper_type_name": "Wet"]
], "2019-07-30": [
    ["changed_time": "02:00 PM", "changed_date": "2019-07-30", "changed_diaper_type_name": "Wet"],
    ["changed_time": "10:00 PM", "changed_date": "2019-07-30", "changed_diaper_type_name": "Dry"]
], "2019-07-29": [
    ["changed_time": "06:00 PM", "changed_date": "2019-07-29", "changed_diaper_type_name": "Dirty"]
]]

Answer (score 8):

In Swift 2.0 you can filter the dictionary and then map the result to an array.

```
let keys = drinks.filter {
    return $0.1.contains("Orange")
}.map {
    return $0.0
}
```

The result will be an array of `String` object representing the matching keys.

Comment: Works, returns returns all keys that have matching values but cryptic.

Comment: "Cryptic" is a harsh word considering filter and map are higher-order functions. The syntax is outdated nowadays, but that's about it

Answer (score 2):

Enumerate through all the dictionary entries and test each value list for the value you want and accumulate the keys where the value is present.

Example, finds all drinks that include the desired value in a list:

```
let drinks = [
    "Soft Drinks": ["Orange", "Cocoa-Cola", "Mountain Dew", "Sprite"],
    "Juice" :["Apple", "Grape"]
]

let value = "Orange"

var keys = [String]()
for (key, list) in drinks {
    if (list.contains(value)) {
        keys.append(key)
    }
}

print("keys: \(keys)")
```

> keys: ["Soft Drinks"]

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy solution in Swift 4:

```
let transport = ["bus": "red", "car": "white", "TARDIS": "blue"]

let key = (transport.filter { $0.value == "blue" }).first?.key
{
    print (key)
}
```

> TARDIS

Answer (score -2):

try this (swift):

```
(dic as NSDictionary).allKeysForObject(<#T##anObject: AnyObject##AnyObject#>)
```

it work for me

Comment: (drinks as NSDictionary).allKeysForObject("Orange") returns an empty array, not "Juice" as requested. by the way, it is  written in the question. please, verify your answer in a playground or another way, before publish.

Comment: relax man.  i just write a  generic template to help someone else have a similar question . i don't write any parameter . you reading too much into my answer